# Characteristic function: fourier transform of probability measure or density?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

In many texts charecteristic function is defined as a Fourier transform of probability density (if random variable admits a density function). Also we can define a charecteristic function as Fourier transform of probability measuer instead (like in Jacod J., Protter P. Probability essentials, second edition, page 104). Are these definitions equal? I'm a bit confused as not all random variables have probability density but probability measuer should always be defined.

Comment: In the context of measure theory, the role of density is played by the [Radon-Nikodym derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem).

Comment: In brief, if $\mu$ is the probability measure, $F$ the corresponding distribution function, and $f$ the probability density function, then $E[e^{itX} ] = \int {e^{itx} d\mu (x)}  = \int {e^{itx} dF(x)}  = \int {e^{itx} f(x)dx}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same.  For a random variable which admits a density function $f$, its distribution measure $\mu$ is given by $\mu(A) = \int_A f dm$, or more compactly $d\mu = f dm$, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.  It is clear that in this case, the Fourier transform of $\mu$ is the same as the Fourier transform of $f$.